# Passing an instance of an object to a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, methods, arguments

I have this method:

```
- (void)postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary toURL:(NSURL *)url forDelegate:(id)delegate withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

I want to pass an instance of an object to this method and later call something like:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishDownload:)]) {
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(didFinishDownload:) withObject:@"test"];
}
```

I guess I have to pass an pointer of the object to the method?

I guess I'll have to use ****, ***** and &. But I don't know where I have to use which of these.

Can you please help me?

SideSwipe

Comment: this question can be deleted. i am very sorry, i just apssed the false kind of object so the selector wasn't called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find that all Objects in Objective C are referenced by pointers. So when you declare an NSString you do something like this:

```
NSString *myString = @"testString";
```

In the same way doing alloc init to create a new object returns a pointer. You can just pass the pointer directly to the method.

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishDownload:)]) {
[delegate performSelector:@selector(didFinishDownload:) withObject:myString];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess `- (void)postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary toURL:(NSURL *)url forDelegate:(id)delegate withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;` is the method declared by you.

U can have

`- (void)postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary toURL:(NSURL *)url forDelegate:(id)delegate withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withObject:(id)obj;`

Comment: oO sry I guess I was not clear about what I want. I declared '- (void)postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary toURL:(NSURL *)url forDelegate:(id)delegate withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;'
delegate shall be an instance of an object passed by me.
but can i simply go by calling it like this? Don't I have to work with pointers and stuff like this to call an method of the 'delegate' passed?

Comment: No, actually the instance of an object itself is a pointer. You can directly send that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you easily do for example

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishDownload:)]) {
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(didFinishDownload:) withObject:identifier];
}
```

Why you say you need to do a kind of pointer operation?